# Service discovery failed[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth

I just finished developing my Application with Android and bluetooth you can send message share files and chat with bluetooth.  It's a very strange application every time it shows an error and other time it works perfectly.  Here is the top of my problems

> E/BluetoothEventLoop.cpp(298): onCreateDeviceResult: D-Bus error: org.bluez.Error.AlreadyExists (Already Exists)`

the second error :

> Service discovery failed[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement

my code :

```
    private BluetoothSocket getLaSocketConnecte(BluetoothDevice myBtServer, UUID uuidToTry)           
    { 
      BluetoothSocket myBSock; 
      try 
      { 
        if (BtAdapter.isDiscovering()) 
        { 
          BtAdapter.cancelDiscovery(); 
        } 
        myBSock = myBtServer.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuidToTry);
        myBSock.connect(); 
        return myBSock; 
      } catch (Exception e) { 
        Log.i(TAG,"IOException . Msg d'erreur :" + e.getMessage()+ e.getStackTrace()); 
      } 
      return null; 
    }
```

And here is the log :

```
04-01 20:38:28.079: I/Connexion(9240): Msg d'erreur : Msg d erreur 

:Service discovery failed
04-01 20:38:28.079: I/Connexion(9240): java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
04-01 20:38:28.079: I/Connexion(9240):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket$SdpHelper.doSdp(BluetoothSocket.java:403)
04-01 20:38:28.079: I/Connexion(9240):  at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:213)
            myBSock.connect();
04-01 20:38:28.079: I/Connexion(9240):  at com.Android.Bt.Connexion.getLaSocketConnecte(Connexion.java:190)
04-01 20:38:28.079: I/Connexion(9240):  at com.Android.Bt.Connexion.connecterA(Connexion.java:149)
            btSock = getLaSocketConnecte(btDevice, uuidList.get(i));
04-01 20:38:28.079: I/Connexion(9240):  at com.Android.Bt.Connexion.ConnecterTousLesAppreils(Connexion.java:293)
            connecterA(device.getKey());
04-01 20:38:28.079: I/Connexion(9240):  at com.Android.Bt.Connexion.EnvoyeBroadcastMsg(Connexion.java:428)
04-01 20:38:28.079: I/Connexion(9240):  at com.Android.Bt.Connexion.broadcastMessage(Connexion.java:205)
04-01 20:38:28.079: I/Connexion(9240):  at com.Android.Bt.BtPaquetReceiver.onReceive(BtPaquetReceiver.java:28)
```

Can you please help me to figure out the solution?

Thanks :)

---

Comment: Please provide your source and logcat

Comment: hi, Eclipse don't give me a line wish there is the problem

Comment: nobody can read code in a comment... add it to the question!

Comment: Please change `Log.i(TAG,"IOException . Msg d'erreur :" + e.getMessage()+ e.getStackTrace());` to `Log.e(TAG,"IOException . Msg d'erreur :" + e.getMessage(), e);` and post the stacktrace you get

Comment: WarrenFait so I repaired the 2 devices and then the problem appears

Comment: the line code wish there is a problem is these one :    myBSock.connect();

Comment: I attach the logcat in the Question

Comment: the problem came from the Bluetooth APi of Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue back then was related to Bluetooth API !